# Configure .netcore project as portable, but publish as selfcontained

Tags: .net-core

I know that it is possible to build/publish .NET Core applications in 2 different ways, namely: **Portable application** (`"type": "platform"`) and **Self-contained application** (`"type": "build"`).

When I create a new application using `dotnet new`, `project.json` by default is set up for the Portable application:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore": "1.0.0-alpha-160629"
      }
    }
  }
```

And it means that my application will depend on the runtime, which is installed on the machine, where I am going to run the application.

But what if I decide, that I want to publish this application in both Portable and Self-contained modes?
When I set the type to be `build` and try to run the application, I receive an error, which, I guess, is expected:

> C:\temp\testproj>dotnet restore && dotnet run
>
> log : Restoring packages for C:\temp\testproj\project.json...
>
> log : Restoring packages for tool 'dotnet-compile-fsc' in  C:\temp\testproj\project.json...
>
> log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path:  C:\temp\testproj\project.lock.json
>
> log  : C:\temp\testproj\project.json
>
> log  : Restore completed in 1973ms.
>
> Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
> 2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
> 3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.

And to make it work I can set add a `runtimes` section in `project.json`, which will list my current machine's architecture as one of the supported.

**The question is:**
Is there a way to publish the application both as self-contained and portable without changing `project.json` each time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by `scripts` section in your `project.json`. You have 4 events - `precompile`, `postcompile`, `prepublish`, `postpublish`. In scripts you can whatever you want like (for example have two `procet.json`, replace and execute with them by `dotnet publish`)

You canread mor about `scripts` section at https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is slightly different to what I imagined a solution would be. I can achieve the same behavior by adding this kind of logic to the build script. I though there is a way without having two different project.json files.